# Password If-Check error

Tags: android, if-statement

Help! I need to check, if first text equals second!

```
pass = readPassFromFile()
if(passTxt.getText().toString()==pass)  
{
    success()
} else {
    fail()
}
```

I entered right password into EditText. Variable pass is a line from file. I used toast to see passwords. Result ('-' is a separator, '[]' is start/end): [Qwerty-Qwerty].

Answer (score 0):

```
pass = readPassFromFile()
if(pass.equalsIgnoreCase(passTxt.getText().toString()))  
{
    success()
} else {
    fail()
}
```

Comment: Unknown method equalIgnorCase of java.lang.String

Comment: It's equalsIgnoreCase.Just move to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java for detail.

Comment: I fixed it 5 minutes ago